# help with procedural wispy / pulled apart cotton-like material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, procedural, photorealism

I'm having a little trouble creating a material similar to the fabric part in the following pictures:
[image: fabric surface over rubberized asphalt]
[image: close up]

This is what my node tree is currently looking like:
[image: node tree]

Here's what my rendering is currently looking like:
[image: current look]

Here's a censored version of the goal:
[image: censored roll]

I'm pretty new to blender and 3d modeling in general but I feel like I'm on the right track with this material, I'm just not sure how to tweak it to make the effect more *photorealistic.*

Getting that pulled apart cotton ball-ish effect on the cloth material is important for the purposes of the image. I tried playing around with hair particles for that but it wasn't really doing what I wanted and it didn't seem to be super cooperative when I was trying to overlay the silk screened text into the material.

Here's a link to the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ilgbgcBtR8Ai4eohZobMBqzXWv7WJoPf).

Let me know if there's anything else I could provide to help or make things more clear.

Comment: It would help if we had a photo reference of what you’re trying to recreate.

Comment: I've added a _censored_ version of what I'm trying to recreate.